# sort struct in alphabetical order (swift4)

Tags: swift, sorting, struct

My code right now appends entries to a struct. If a button is pressed it adds the entry to a label and sorts the label. So Button is pressed -> entered into struct -> struct is printed and sorted on a label. I want each entry in the struct to be sorted programmatically just like I have it doing via action button affecting label.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var a: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    var contacts = [Person]()

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
        contacts.append(Person(name: a.text!))
        let sortedContacts = contacts.sorted {
            ($0.name < $1.name)
        }
        label.text = contacts.count == 0 ? "" : sortedContacts.map { $0.description }.joined(separator: "\n")

    }

    struct Person {
        var name: String

        var description: String {
            return   "\(name)"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a few notes on your updated code. Make your Person property name a constant. description property can just `return name`. You forgot to add to Person a CustomStringConvertible protocol `struct Person: CustomStringConvertible`. And dont use `count == 0` to check if your array is empty. Use isEmpty property `contacts.isEmpty ?`

Comment: Sam, I'm not clear what your question is. Sure you can tweak around the edges like Leo and rmaddy have noted, but they accomplish something very much like what you've got. If you're not seeing multiple lines in your label, make sure to set `numberOfLines` to either zero or some value greater than `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to sort your array of `Person` objects then sort `contacts`:

```
@IBAction func save(_ sender: Any) {
    contacts.append(Person(name: a.text!))
    contacts.sort { $0.name < $1.name }
    label.text = contacts.map { $0.description }.joined(separator: "\n")
}
```

And as mentioned in the comments, you should update your `Person` struct:

```
struct Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    let name: String

    var description: String {
        return name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort `myStruct` like below :

```
Person.myStruct.sorted { $0 < $1 }
```

Comment: I am trying to sort var name not static var myStruct. How would I do that?